# Cannot open URL in UIWebView in ios 9.0

Tags: uiwebview, ios9, xcode7

I get the following message when i try to open a URL in UIWebView-

> App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.

I already tried the method given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http/) but I get the same error report at the console

[image: My info.plist]

[image: Error At Console]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NSAppTransportSecurity** add to info.plist , data  type is Dictionary, then add an item **NSAllowsArbitraryLoads** , which is boolean value and set it to YES, then restart the Xcode project and run.

**NSAppTransportSecurity**: - 
 A dictionary containing the settings for overriding default App Transport Security behaviors. The top level key for the app’s Info.plist file.

Comment: That did not help. Please see the Screenshot I just added. That's the steps you have asked, right?

Comment: @SidharthJDev- Open your .plist  as a source code, which is an XML file. then write                                        <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>  then open plist as property list. Please use these specific keywords

Comment: I cannot write individual domains..I need the webview to blindly load all domains

Comment: @SidharthJDev-What do you mean exactly by **individual domains**?